# Wallet phrase recovery

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet-security

I already have 12 phrase for my wallet but they are not in order.Is there any program to re-arrange the wallet phrase?

Comment: It's not hard to write one yourself. https://ideone.com/RwSiEs (It runs out of juice on the free version of Ideone but just run it locally or pay for an account, or maybe run it on a different online code site like https://repl.it/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, most wallets will generate the words for the seed phrase at random, so there is no way to infer the order after they've been generated. The order of the words is part of the seed phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You must record the 12 word mnemonic to your cryptosteel IN ORDER.

How could you not understand that before starting out?

Comment: It is for a 90 usdt quiz . Hee hee